Comic with aliens making humans shorter so they can take over
Back in the early 80s I "inherited" a bunch of comic books from some older neighbourhood kid who'd grown out of them. I would have been 13 or so.
They were not my usual fare. I was into Richie Rich, Archie, Peanuts, Spiderman, these were a little bit darker. For example, I remember one of them was a Ghost Rider comic that featured Satan. Many of the others were anthology comics with several, unconnected stories. I was into Conan at the time and they seemed like a comic version of Weird Tales.
The particular story I'm remembering probably wasn't the main feature and I don't think it appeared on the cover.
What I remember:

The main protagonist (let's call him Shorty, because he was) was reading his son (not named, but called Junior) a bedtime story. The book was "The Little Men", and Shorty was sick of reading it. Junior's response was that he liked stories about dwarfs. Grumbling, Shorty read it.
I think there was a news item on TV about how many tiny kids are being born.
After the bedtime story, Shorty leaves the house to go for a drive with his much taller friend. Let's call him Lurch.
Shorty and Lurch end up in the countryside and Lurch lurches off somewhere.
Shorty meets up with a bunch of guys - even shorter than he was - and their alien spaceship. The aliens were all dressed similarly as mini construction workers, I think they even wore hardhats.
It turns out the alien's plan was to take over the world, but they need to make sure humans are small enough to boss around so they've been putting stuff in our water to inhibit growth.
The aliens were wearing masks, at one point they removed them and underneath they were demonically lizard-like. Shorty said something like "Good Lord, their faces!"
Shorty tells them there plan isn't sort of working.  Yes, there are lots of small babies but there also lots of tall humans being born. He tries to convince them that the growth inhibitor has a side effect that is causing excessive growth in some individuals.
As proof, he and Lurch stand together overlooking a pool where they can seen side by side.
The alien ship leaves. I don't think Lurch ever knew what was going on.
The final scene is back at home. Mrs Shorty asks him what he's doing. I'm throwing Junior's book "The Little Men" out the window, he says. No more dwarf stories for him!

